# C# scan list against master list for missing items

Tags: c#, list, compare

I have a master list that has the values for tables of a database I know to be correct:

```
masterList: List<string>(){ "business", "customer", "location", "employee", etc}
```

And I've queried a new database that is supposed to be identical. My test will tell me if I have any errors in the scripts my team has made to make this new DB. tablesList is supposed to the be the return of my query:

```
tablesList: List<string>(){ "business", "customer", "location", "employee", etc}
```

So in practice they are supposed to be the same, but to test errors, I want to compare the tablesList against the masterList to make sure all needed tables are there. As a copy of this process, I'm also reversing the search, in case there are any extra tables that are not there on the masterList.

**Question: How do I compare a list against a master list, and return items that don't match up?**

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with c# .net Core 2.0.

Here is what I've been trying so far:

```
var errorsList = new List<string>();
tablesList = QuerySchemaForTables();
masterList = GrabMasterTableList();
foreach(var item in masterList)
                    errorsList.Add(tablesList.Where(x => x.Contains(item)));
```

But with this, I'm getting the error:

> cannot convert from IEnumerable to string

Comment: That's not the error you're getting. Tell us the complete text of the error.

Comment: "Arguement 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string' "

Comment: In the question, please. I already know what the error message is. You need to tell the people who didn't paste your code into the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the two directions of errors using LINQ. No need for the loop:

```
var missingInMasterList = tableList.Where(x => !masterList.Contains(x)).ToList();
var missingInTableList = masterList.Where(x => !tableList.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: This has produced the results I've been looking for. When I test my master list against a list I know is missing items and has extras that the master does not have, this gives me a way to output them.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like that;

```
var errorList = tableList.Where(x => !masterList.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the differences using `.Except()`, which is one of the `IEnumerable` [set operations](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/05/05/c.net-little-wonders-the-linq-set-operations----theyre-not.aspx):

```
var missingTables = masterList.Except(tablesList);
var extraTables = tablesList.Except(masterList);
```

Then, to create your error message, you can join the items in these `IEnumerables` with a comma into a single string using `string.Join()`:

```
var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();

if (missingTables.Any())
{
    errorMessage.AppendLine("Missing Tables: " + string.Join(", ", missingTables));
}

if (extraTables.Any())
{
    errorMessage.AppendLine("Extra Tables: " + string.Join(", ", extraTables));
}
```

Then you can output your results by checking the length of `errorMessage` to determine if any errors were encountered:

```
if (errorMessage.Length > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No extra or missing tables detected");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find all items that are in the `tablesList` but not in the `masterList` use `.Contains`:

```
var errorsList = tableList.Where(x => !masterList.Contains(x));
```

But I recommend you use a `HashSet<String>` for `masterList` so search for an item in it will be in `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`:

```
var masterCollection = new HashSet<String>(GrabMasterTableList());
var errorsList = tableList.Where(x => !masterCollection.Contains(x));
```

---

As for the problem with your code as you posted:

```
foreach(var item in masterList)
    errorsList.Add(tablesList.Where(x => x.Contains(item))); // <-- error
```

As the error points out, Linq's `.Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` whereas `.Add` expects a single item of the type of the collection, which in this case is a single `string`. You could use `.AddRange` instead but I think a better use all together is what I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

I think better to use is `Except()`  as follows

```
var MasterList =  new List<string> { "business", "customer", "location", "employee"};
var ChildList = new List<String> {  "customer", "location", "employee" };

var filter = MasterList.Except(ChildList);
```

This will values those are not in `ChildList`.You can also do vice versa.

Comment: Don't use `List` as the name of your variables. It's confusing. You can use `list` if you really want, but it's always better to use a more meaningful name.

Comment: Agree and Updated. Thanks for taking a note of it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is presently trying to add an IEnumerable to a List.

If you want to add all the matches you should AddRange instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var errorsList = new List<string>();
tablesList = QuerySchemaForTables();
masterList = GrabMasterTableList();
foreach(var item in masterList)
    errorsList.AddRange(tablesList.Where(x => x.Contains(item)));
```

Comment: What is `x` in `Where(x => x.Contains(item))`? I already know.

Comment: It appears that ```x``` is the return value of ```GrabMasterTableList```, which seems to be shown as ```tablesList: List<string>(){ "business", "customer", "location", "employee", etc}```

Comment: To me and to the compiler, it appears that `x` is one of the strings in `tablesList`.